# How can I pop up the system property window in windows7

Tags: windows-7, operating-system, environment-variables, system-properties

I want to open the system property window to change environment variable in Windows7. I know how to open that window, and used to use that window sometimes before, but today I opened the window as usual, It does not appear. How can I open it?

Comment: Can you show us the code you use?

Comment: I didn't write any code today, but I only could access the system property window using "sysdm.cpl enter" command in cmd without any GUI.

Comment: Hit `<Windows>`+`<Pause>`

Comment: Thanks, Alexander. But that does not work. ㅠ_ㅠ Is there any other way to pop up the window?0?

Comment: If you try to run that same command from cmd what does it say?

Comment: It just shows the system property window without any code in cmd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check why that command stopped to work in your environment, meanwhile try with this (from *command line* or from *Run*):

```
rundll32 sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables
```

Also check this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144191%28v=vs.85%29.aspx